# What is the best tool to analyse individual user?

Tags: analytics

There are lots of tool to analyse a segment of unknown users, eq: Google Analytics, Flurry. But my case is different, my user pool is limited and registered. And i need to make an overview about what a user in our app. The closest thing i can find is the user explorer feature of Google Analytics, but it list the user's action step by step, which is too detailed. i want to how much time the user sent on a page, or how many time the user trigger a feature. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic This is opinion based and not really a problem to solve or answer. I like Coca Cola zero, some other guy might like Pepsi better.

Comment: no i am asking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

KISSmetrics should solve your problems.